# Restore data from crashed MariaDB

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Need to retrieve a mysql dump from suddenly stopped database.
Database worked in kubernetes cluster as a bitnami/mariadb chart of version 6.7.4.
Was configured a slave and month ago it was stopped, but replication process was still in progress.
Database was crashed probably due to lack of disk space (because of huge binary logs )

I have a full snapshot of database data directory.
I have a full database schema, so I tried to install empty schema and replace all empty .idb files into same with data

After replacing and restarting mariadb I see an errors like that:

```
MariaDB [store]> select * from admin;
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'store.admin' doesn't exist in engine
```

I ran mysql_upgrade but stil see same errors:

```
backend % mysql_upgrade -u store -p
Enter password: 
Phase 1/7: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.global_priv                                  OK
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.index_stats                                  OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.roles_mapping                                OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.table_stats                                  OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.transaction_registry                         OK
Phase 2/7: Installing used storage engines... Skipped
Phase 3/7: Fixing views
mysql.user                                         OK
sys.host_summary                                   OK
sys.host_summary_by_file_io                        OK
sys.host_summary_by_file_io_type                   OK
sys.host_summary_by_stages                         OK
sys.host_summary_by_statement_latency              OK
sys.host_summary_by_statement_type                 OK
sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_schema                  OK
sys.innodb_buffer_stats_by_table                   OK
sys.innodb_lock_waits                              OK
sys.io_by_thread_by_latency                        OK
sys.io_global_by_file_by_bytes                     OK
sys.io_global_by_file_by_latency                   OK
sys.io_global_by_wait_by_bytes                     OK
sys.io_global_by_wait_by_latency                   OK
sys.latest_file_io                                 OK
sys.memory_by_host_by_current_bytes                OK
sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes              OK
sys.memory_by_user_by_current_bytes                OK
sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes                 OK
sys.memory_global_total                            OK
sys.metrics                                        OK
sys.processlist                                    OK
sys.ps_check_lost_instrumentation                  OK
sys.schema_auto_increment_columns                  OK
sys.schema_index_statistics                        OK
sys.schema_object_overview                         OK
sys.schema_redundant_indexes                       OK
sys.schema_table_lock_waits                        OK
sys.schema_table_statistics                        OK
sys.schema_table_statistics_with_buffer            OK
sys.schema_tables_with_full_table_scans            OK
sys.schema_unused_indexes                          OK
sys.session                                        OK
sys.session_ssl_status                             OK
sys.statement_analysis                             OK
sys.statements_with_errors_or_warnings             OK
sys.statements_with_full_table_scans               OK
sys.statements_with_runtimes_in_95th_percentile    OK
sys.statements_with_sorting                        OK
sys.statements_with_temp_tables                    OK
sys.user_summary                                   OK
sys.user_summary_by_file_io                        OK
sys.user_summary_by_file_io_type                   OK
sys.user_summary_by_stages                         OK
sys.user_summary_by_statement_latency              OK
sys.user_summary_by_statement_type                 OK
sys.version                                        OK
sys.wait_classes_global_by_avg_latency             OK
sys.wait_classes_global_by_latency                 OK
sys.waits_by_host_by_latency                       OK
sys.waits_by_user_by_latency                       OK
sys.waits_global_by_latency                        OK
sys.x$host_summary                                 OK
sys.x$host_summary_by_file_io                      OK
sys.x$host_summary_by_file_io_type                 OK
sys.x$host_summary_by_stages                       OK
sys.x$host_summary_by_statement_latency            OK
sys.x$host_summary_by_statement_type               OK
sys.x$innodb_buffer_stats_by_schema                OK
sys.x$innodb_buffer_stats_by_table                 OK
sys.x$innodb_lock_waits                            OK
sys.x$io_by_thread_by_latency                      OK
sys.x$io_global_by_file_by_bytes                   OK
sys.x$io_global_by_file_by_latency                 OK
sys.x$io_global_by_wait_by_bytes                   OK
sys.x$io_global_by_wait_by_latency                 OK
sys.x$latest_file_io                               OK
sys.x$memory_by_host_by_current_bytes              OK
sys.x$memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes            OK
sys.x$memory_by_user_by_current_bytes              OK
sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes               OK
sys.x$memory_global_total                          OK
sys.x$processlist                                  OK
sys.x$ps_digest_95th_percentile_by_avg_us          OK
sys.x$ps_digest_avg_latency_distribution           OK
sys.x$ps_schema_table_statistics_io                OK
sys.x$schema_flattened_keys                        OK
sys.x$schema_index_statistics                      OK
sys.x$schema_table_lock_waits                      OK
sys.x$schema_table_statistics                      OK
sys.x$schema_table_statistics_with_buffer          OK
sys.x$schema_tables_with_full_table_scans          OK
sys.x$session                                      OK
sys.x$statement_analysis                           OK
sys.x$statements_with_errors_or_warnings           OK
sys.x$statements_with_full_table_scans             OK
sys.x$statements_with_runtimes_in_95th_percentile  OK
sys.x$statements_with_sorting                      OK
sys.x$statements_with_temp_tables                  OK
sys.x$user_summary                                 OK
sys.x$user_summary_by_file_io                      OK
sys.x$user_summary_by_file_io_type                 OK
sys.x$user_summary_by_stages                       OK
sys.x$user_summary_by_statement_latency            OK
sys.x$user_summary_by_statement_type               OK
sys.x$wait_classes_global_by_avg_latency           OK
sys.x$wait_classes_global_by_latency               OK
sys.x$waits_by_host_by_latency                     OK
sys.x$waits_by_user_by_latency                     OK
sys.x$waits_global_by_latency                      OK
Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
Phase 5/7: Fixing table and database names
Phase 6/7: Checking and upgrading tables
Processing databases
information_schema
performance_schema
store
store.account
Error    : Table 'store.account' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.account_event
Error    : Table 'store.account_event' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.account_setting
Error    : Table 'store.account_setting' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.admin
Error    : Table 'store.admin' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_actions_daily
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_actions_daily' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_daily
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_daily' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_daily_total
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_daily_total' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_monthly
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_monthly' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_weekly
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_weekly' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_trainer
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_trainer' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.apple_price
Error    : Table 'store.apple_price' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.apple_tier_price
Error    : Table 'store.apple_tier_price' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.country
Error    : Table 'store.country' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course
Error    : Table 'store.course' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container
Error    : Table 'store.course_container' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container_course_dietary_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_container_course_dietary_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container_course_education_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_container_course_education_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container_course_workout_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_container_course_workout_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_day
Error    : Table 'store.course_day' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_dietary_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_dietary_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_education_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_education_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_price
Error    : Table 'store.course_price' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_workout_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_workout_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.credit_card
Error    : Table 'store.credit_card' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.currency_rate
Error    : Table 'store.currency_rate' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.daily_nutrition
Error    : Table 'store.daily_nutrition' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.daily_recipe
Error    : Table 'store.daily_recipe' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.diet
Error    : Table 'store.diet' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.diet_recipe
Error    : Table 'store.diet_recipe' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.dietary_program
Error    : Table 'store.dietary_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.dietary_program_day
Error    : Table 'store.dietary_program_day' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.education_program
Error    : Table 'store.education_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.education_program_day
Error    : Table 'store.education_program_day' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.exercise
Error    : Table 'store.exercise' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.exercise_step
Error    : Table 'store.exercise_step' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.file
Error    : Table 'store.file' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.food
Error    : Table 'store.food' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.food_copy
Error    : Table 'store.food_copy' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.lesson
Error    : Table 'store.lesson' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.lesson_pack
Error    : Table 'store.lesson_pack' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.lesson_pack_lesson
Error    : Table 'store.lesson_pack_lesson' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.marathon
Error    : Table 'store.marathon' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.marathon_day
Error    : Table 'store.marathon_day' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.note
Error    : Table 'store.note' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.nutrition
Error    : Table 'store.nutrition' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.nutrition_recipe
Error    : Table 'store.nutrition_recipe' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payment_intention
Error    : Table 'store.payment_intention' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payment_transaction
Error    : Table 'store.payment_transaction' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payment_transaction_apple_in_app
Error    : Table 'store.payment_transaction_apple_in_app' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payment_transaction_bt
Error    : Table 'store.payment_transaction_bt' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payment_transaction_cp
Error    : Table 'store.payment_transaction_cp' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payment_transaction_ym
Error    : Table 'store.payment_transaction_ym' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payout_transaction
Error    : Table 'store.payout_transaction' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.payout_transaction_payment_transaction
Error    : Table 'store.payout_transaction_payment_transaction' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.phone_verification
Error    : Table 'store.phone_verification' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.product
Error    : Table 'store.product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.recipe
Error    : Table 'store.recipe' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.recipe_food
Error    : Table 'store.recipe_food' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.recipe_step
Error    : Table 'store.recipe_step' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.sales_order
Error    : Table 'store.sales_order' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.sales_order_item
Error    : Table 'store.sales_order_item' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.time_slot
Error    : Table 'store.time_slot' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_group_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_group_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_home_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_home_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_month_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_month_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_trainer
Error    : Table 'store.top_trainer' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer
Error    : Table 'store.trainer' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer_action
Error    : Table 'store.trainer_action' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer_chat_link
Error    : Table 'store.trainer_chat_link' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer_event
Error    : Table 'store.trainer_event' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer_event_message                    OK
store.trainer_notification_task
Error    : Table 'store.trainer_notification_task' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer_payout_info
Error    : Table 'store.trainer_payout_info' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.trainer_status_message
Error    : Table 'store.trainer_status_message' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.training
Error    : Table 'store.training' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.training_exercise
Error    : Table 'store.training_exercise' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user
Error    : Table 'store.user' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_course
Error    : Table 'store.user_course' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_course_job
Error    : Table 'store.user_course_job' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_device
Error    : Table 'store.user_device' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_activity
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_activity' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_belly
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_belly' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_biceps
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_biceps' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_bust
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_bust' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_calf
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_calf' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_gender
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_gender' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_height
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_height' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_hips
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_hips' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_lactation
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_lactation' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_neck
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_neck' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_single_hip
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_single_hip' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_waist
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_waist' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_measurement_weight
Error    : Table 'store.user_measurement_weight' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_product
Error    : Table 'store.user_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_progress_report
Error    : Table 'store.user_progress_report' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_progress_report_request
Error    : Table 'store.user_progress_report_request' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_trainer
Error    : Table 'store.user_trainer' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.user_trainer_referrer
Error    : Table 'store.user_trainer_referrer' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.video
Error    : Table 'store.video' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.workout_program
Error    : Table 'store.workout_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.workout_program_day
Error    : Table 'store.workout_program_day' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
sys
sys.sys_config                                     OK
test

Repairing tables
store.account
Error    : Table 'store.account' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.account_event
Error    : Table 'store.account_event' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.account_setting
Error    : Table 'store.account_setting' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.admin
Error    : Table 'store.admin' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_actions_daily
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_actions_daily' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_daily
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_daily' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_daily_total
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_daily_total' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_monthly
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_monthly' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_report_weekly
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_report_weekly' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.aggregated_trainer
Error    : Table 'store.aggregated_trainer' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.apple_price
Error    : Table 'store.apple_price' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.apple_tier_price
Error    : Table 'store.apple_tier_price' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.country
Error    : Table 'store.country' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course
Error    : Table 'store.course' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container
Error    : Table 'store.course_container' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container_course_dietary_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_container_course_dietary_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container_course_education_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_container_course_education_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_container_course_workout_program
Error    : Table 'store.course_container_course_workout_program' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.course_day
Error    : Table 'store.payout_transaction_payment_transaction' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.phone_verification
Error    : Table 'store.phone_verification' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.product
Error    : Table 'store.product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.recipe
Error    : Table 'store.recipe' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.recipe_food
Error    : Table 'store.recipe_food' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.recipe_step
Error    : Table 'store.recipe_step' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.sales_order
Error    : Table 'store.sales_order' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.sales_order_item
Error    : Table 'store.sales_order_item' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.time_slot
Error    : Table 'store.time_slot' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_group_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_group_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_home_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_home_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_month_product
Error    : Table 'store.top_month_product' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
store.top_product
Error    : Table 'store.workout_program_day' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
Phase 7/7: Running 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES'
OK
```

Is there any way to restore this data?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have full snapshot of database directory, why you don't just copy the whole thing to your drive and point the new service to the data folder instead? Assuming that full snapshot is the whole `MariaDB XX.X` folder

Comment: You cannot restore individual ibd files. Do the whole datadir.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask on [DBA.se]